# Invoking command prompt from Tcl in windows with key

Tags: cmd, tcl

I create a simple script in command prompt, `test.cmd`.
When I run

```
c:\test.cmd myname
is your MyName [Y/n]
```

now I put `Y` or `n` and press enter to continue. How can i automate this in Tcl script?

I created `test.tcl`

```
exec test.cmd myname &
after 500
puts  "Y\r"
```

but it is not working.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
set input "Y"
puts [exec test.cmd << $input]
```

Refer to the [`exec`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) documentation